Modulus operator in Vega
Is there a modulus operator for formula expressions in Vega?
I have found a mod operator in most other languages and thought it would be a common place in any programmatic language.
I have looked into the online documentation at https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/ and could not find a relevant operator. Are there any alternatives?
Thanks in advance for your assistance.

It is just javascript so it is %

That's a remainder operator. Not the same thing.

Can you give an example of the operation and output you would expect?
